# How to convert users' casual time input to an accepted time format in python DateTimeField?

Tags: python, django

In my Django application, there is a field that accepts User/ Admin's input time. The expect outcomes would be:

1. Input 7 then the system will convert it to 7:00
2. Input 715, it would be recognized at 7:15.
   The same 2011 -->20:11, 015-->0015

How should I do it? Any comments?

P.S. I don't have code because I would like to know the apprach first. Thank you!

Comment: "P.S. I don't have code because I would like to know the apprach first. Thank you!" That's not how you learn. If you don't have any code, at least provide us a bullet point list of how you would approach the problem!

Comment: @warnbergg I was thinking about disable the ":" enforce validation format?

Answer (score 1):

You might start off with something as simple as this using substring functions.

```
while True:
    casual = input("Please enter your time:")
    if (casual == "End"):
        break
    if (len(casual) <= 2 or len(casual) > 4):
        print("Please enter three or four digits")
        continue
    if len(casual) == 3:
        hour = casual[0:1]
        if (hour == "0"):
            hour = "00"
        the_time = hour + ":" + casual[1:3]
    else:
        the_time = casual[0:2] + ":" + casual[2:4]
    
    print("The time is:", the_time)
```

You might want to add in a bit of error checking so that the range of hours is from "00" to "23" and the range of minutes is from "00" to "59".

Comment: Thanks! I need to adapt it in my django app and decide if accept the answer or not. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  Have fun coding.

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you need

```
from datetime import time
time_input = input()

if len(time_input) <= 2:
  time_input += '00'

time_format = time(hour=int(time_input[:-2]), minute=int(time_input[-2:]))

print(time_format)
from datetime import time
time_input = input()

if len(time_input) <= 2:
  time_input += '00'

time_format = time(hour=int(time_input[:-2]), minute=int(time_input[-2:]))

print(time_format)
```

Comment: Simao Caixeta, I appreciate your work. Just as I commented to NoBakker, let me check a bit. Thank you!